# Replace NULL with nulliff returns different query results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build a dynamic query, I will pass a parameter and if the parameter is empty, then the query returns all the items I have in the table. The second query returns all the items I have in the table. The first query returns a much shorter result.

Any ideas?

```
select ...
where table.code = isnull(nullif('',''),table.code)

select ...
where table.code = isnull(null,table.code)
```

Comment: Can you show us a SQLFiddle of what's happening?

Answer (score 3):

This simple test shows the problem :

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF('', ''), 'TEST')
```

Instead of returning TEST, as expected, it returns **'T'**, because the first NULLIF returns a null of varchar(1) type (the type of its parameters), so the return value of ISNULL is also casted to varchar(1).

I would simply use COALESCE instead of ISNULL (it doesn't try to convert the return value to the type of the first value) :

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF('', ''), 'TEST')
```

This one returns the correct value **'TEST'**.

So to fix your query you only need to replace ISNULL by COALESCE :

```
select ...
where table.code = coalesce(nullif('',''),table.code)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `isnull()` function twice as :

```
select ...
where table.code = isnull( isnull(null,@yourparam),table.code)
```

if `@yourparam` is `null` then `isnull(null,@yourparam)` returns `null`, too.

Answer (score 1):

Let your parameter be denoted by @param that you supply in the query at runtime.

Your query could then be

```
declare @param varchar(50)
select * from table
where nullif(@param, '') is null or table.code = @param
```

for example see following two snippets, first query will return result only when there exists a table by the name you supplied, second query will return all records

```
declare @param varchar(50) = 'table_from_your_db'
select * 
from information_schema.tables t
where nullif(@param, '') is null or t.table_name = @param
```

```
declare @param varchar(50) = '' 
select * 
from information_schema.tables t
where nullif(@param, '') is null or t.table_name = @param
```